# Sine wave 'frequency' in recorded signals

Tags: software-defined-radio, frequency

I'm trying to replicate a signal from a remote using another wireless transmitter (a cc1101 to be exact). I got somewhere, but I am stuck, and have a fundamental question

[image]

At the top is the signal I'm trying to replicate, and at the bottom we have the signal my transmitter is currently sending.

Apart from the amplitude and the fact that some of the bits seem off I have a main question:

In the original signal I see a single sine wave (2pi-ish) per bit, but if I zoom in on my signal a single bit consists of a lot of full waves (like 16 pi worth).

I am confused about what these waves even mean? I would say it has to do with frequency as my signal just has more waves in the same amount of time. But both signals are recorded at 434MHz, so the frequency should be the same? Is there more than 1 frequency? Am I missing something here? And how do I make my transmitter transmit a single wave per bit?

PS. Sorry if this is a simple question, I'm just getting into all this radio stuff. Also any other tips and tricks for my remote replication would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Well, how was the signal acquired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in waveform display might be that your two 434 MHz oscillators are actually at slightly different frequencies, maybe around a +-14 Hz or maybe ~300 ppm difference.